# Running Mailmerge more than one time

Tags: excel, vba, email, ms-word, mailmerge

so I have the code bellow (its macro sending emails with mail merge from excel file) and when I run it for the first time it's OK but if I run it for the second time I'm getting the 462 (The remove server machine does not exist or is unavailable). I know that this is caused by occupied variable. But I did everything that I know to prevent this. Could someone tell me how to adjust my code so it can run multiple times without closing the file?

```
Sub Send_Emails()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Dim Doc1 As Document, Doc2 As Document, Doc3 As Document, Doc4 As Document
    Dim StrDoc As String, ListOfDocuments As String

    Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    ListOfDocuments = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\ListOfDocuments.docx"
    Set Doc1 = wrd.Documents.Open(ListOfDocuments)

    With Doc1.MailMerge
      If .State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute
      End If
    End With
    
    Set Doc2 = ActiveDocument
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\Recipients.docx")
    
    Call EmailMergeTableMaker(Doc2)

    With Doc2
      .SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\Recipients.docx")
    End With
    
    Set Doc3 = Documents.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\SupervisorEmail.docx", _
      AddToRecentFiles:=False)
      
    With Doc3.MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdEMail
      .OpenDataSource Name:=(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\Recipients.docx"), ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, _
        LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", _
        SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
      If .State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute
      End If
    End With
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\EmailsToSend.docx")
    Set Doc4 = Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\EmailsToSend.docx")
    
    Doc3.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set Doc3 = Nothing
    
    Call SendEmailsOutlook
    
    Doc1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Doc2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Doc4.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Set Doc1 = Nothing
    Set Doc2 = Nothing
    Set Doc4 = Nothing
    
    wrd.Quit
    Set wrd = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'ThisWorkbook.Close
    
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    'Application.Quit
    
End Sub
Sub SendEmailsOutlook()

  Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim j As Long
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
  Dim Source As Document, MailList As Document
  Dim Recipient As String, MailListDocument As String, SourceDocument As String
  
  MailListDocument = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\Recipients.docx"
  SourceDocument = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\EmailsToSend.docx"
  
  Set MailList = Documents.Open(MailListDocument)
  Set Source = Documents.Open(SourceDocument)
  

    For j = 1 To Source.Sections.Count - 1
        Set oItem = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(olMailItem)
            For Each oAccount In Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts
                If oAccount = "xxxxxx" Then 'xxxxxx
                    With oItem
                    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxxxxx"
                    '.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "xxxxxx"
                    .Subject = "xxxxxx"
                    .HTMLBody = Source.Sections(j).Range.Text
                    Recipient = Left(MailList.Tables(1).Cell(j + 1, 1).Range.Text, Len(MailList.Tables(1).Cell(j + 1, 1).Range.Text) - 1)
                    If Len(Recipient) < 3 Then Exit For
                    .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
                    .To = "xxxxxx"
                    '.To = Recipient
                    .Send
                    End With
                    Set oItem = Nothing
                End If
            Next
    Next j

End Sub
Sub EmailMergeTableMaker(DocName As Document)

    Dim oTbl As Object
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim oRow As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    Dim strTxt As String
    
    
    With DocName
      .Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
      Call TableJoiner
      For Each oTbl In .Tables
      j = 4
        With oTbl
          i = .Columns.Count - j
          For Each oRow In .Rows
            Set oRng = oRow.Cells(j).Range
            With oRng
              .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCell, Count:=i
              .Cells.Merge
              strTxt = Replace(.Text, vbCr, vbTab)
              On Error Resume Next
              If Len(strTxt) > 1 Then .Text = Left(strTxt, Len(strTxt) - 2)
            End With
          Next
        End With
      Next
      For Each oTbl In .Tables
        For i = 1 To j
          oTbl.Columns(i).Cells.Merge
        Next
      Next
      
      With .Tables(1)
        .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(1)
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Recipient"
        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Name"
        .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Gender"
        .Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "List"
      End With
      .Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
      
      Call TableJoiner
      
    End With
    
    Set oRng = Nothing
    
End Sub
Private Sub TableJoiner()
    
    Dim wrd2 As Object, doc As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim oTbl As Table
    
    Set wrd2 = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set doc = wrd2.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Germany\Supervisors\Recipients.docx")
    
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
      With tbl.Range.Next
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then .Delete
      End With
    Next
    
    Set wrd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I will test it out.

Comment: What you suggested solved the problem. Thanks!